# Integrate Orbeon with Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, orbeon

My question is very simple. I have an Orbeon form and I want to store the XML file of the form in Alfresco. What is the easiest way to do this integration.
I know that Orbeon PE has this feature but I would like to use CE.
I also checked http://blog.ossgeeks.org/2011/12/alfresco-persistence-layer-for-orbeon.html but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: If you found that blog post you may have already seen this, but for others, be sure to read this presentation on Alfresco-Orbeon integration that was given at Alfresco DevCon: http://www.slideshare.net/alfresco/using-alfresco-and-orbeon-to-implement-a-local-egovernment-portal

Answer (score 1):

Using or creating an Alfresco *persistence layer* is the way to go. Most likely this means either:

1. Getting the persistence layer Alexey mentions in that [blog post](http://blog.ossgeeks.org/2011/12/alfresco-persistence-layer-for-orbeon.html) to work. Maybe you could get feedback about the specific issue you have by posting a more details description as a comment on that post.
2. Writing your own persistence layer. This might be simpler than what you imagine, especially if you don't need all the operations (e.g. if you don't need *search* since you won't be using the summary page).